# Can we make HTML5 video fullscreen on Dolphin browser

Tags: html5-video, dolphin-browser

I have tested the [**HTML5 video player**](http://videojs.com/), it can make HTML5 video fullscreen on Android Chrome browser but not Dolphin browser.

Is someone know what is the way to make HTML5 video fullscreen on **Dolphin browser**?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested that [**jplayer**](http://jplayer.org/) can make HTML5 video in fullscreen, ever in Android 4.x default browser and Dolphin browser, the config should refer to below code:

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function () {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                m4v: "demo.m4v"
            });
        },
        swfPath: "js",
        supplied: "webmv, ogv, m4v",
        fullScreen: true
    });
```